# Loops & Volume increase for audio within processing

Tags: java, processing

I am a beginner to all of this. My aim is to create a processing file that when loaded will play a melody for 30 seconds. The melody should change several times through the sequence.

I am looking to loop my `outplaynotes` for 30 seconds. Also is there a way to increase the volume of these notes?  I want to play audio samples on top of the playnotes but the samples are much louder then the playnotes. What is the best way to level them out, volume wise?

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioOutput out;
myDelay;

void setup() {
    size(800, 300, P2D);
    minim = new Minim(this);
    out = minim.getLineOut();
    myDelay = new Delay(1.5,0.5, false,false);

    out.pauseNotes();

    out.setTempo(240);

    out.playNote( 0.00, 1.0, new ToneInstrument( 80, 0.5, out ) );
    out.playNote( 2.00, 0.5, new ToneInstrument( 100, 0.5, out ) );
    out.playNote( 3.00, 0.5, new ToneInstrument( 250, 0.5, out ) );
    out.playNote( 4.00, 1.0, new ToneInstrument( 90, 0.5, out ) );
    out.playNote( 5.00, 1.0, new ToneInstrument( 100, 0.5, out ) );
    out.playNote( 6.00, 0.5, new ToneInstrument( 120, 0.5, out ) );
    out.playNote( 7.00, 0.5, new ToneInstrument( 270, 0.5, out ) );
    out.playNote( 8.00, 1.0, new ToneInstrument( 110, 0.5, out ) );
    out.resumeNotes();
}

class ToneInstrument implements Instrument {

    Oscil       wave;
    Damp damp;

    ToneInstrument(float frequency, float amplitude, AudioOutput output) {
        out = output;

        wave = new Oscil(frequency, amplitude, Waves.TRIANGLE);
        damp = new Damp(0.0001, 1.5);
        wave.patch(damp);
        wave.patch(myDelay);
    }

    void noteOn(float dur) {
        damp.setDampTimeFromDuration(dur);
        damp.activate();
        damp.patch(out);
    }

    void noteOff() {
        damp.unpatchAfterDamp(out);
    }

}

void draw() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the looping, you can use [the `frameCount` variable](https://processing.org/reference/frameCount.html) and [the modulo operator](https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html) to do something every X frames. Here's a small example that simply prints something to the console every 60 frames, or once per second:

```
void draw(){
    if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
       println("frameCount: " + frameCount);
    }
}
```

You would do something similar, except you would be playing notes instead of printing to the console.

As for the volume, your best friend is [the Minim documentation](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/). For example the `AudioOutput` class has a couple functions for setting the volume. I'd start there if I were you.

Comment: I have 16 playnotes, how can i loop them all together with frame count?

Comment: @Ham You'll have better luck if you try something. You could store the notes and their frame durations in arrays, or you could create a class that holds that information. Then just iterate over that data structure and check the frame durations, and then trigger the corresponding notes. Try something out and post a new question if you get stuck.